# Flask - get user input and pass it to backend

Tags: python, flask

I want to get user input and validate if it is correct or not in the backend...
There is something missing but I am not able to figure it out:

run.py code:

```
@app.route('/game', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def game():
    global answer_number 
    global user_correct 
    global user_wrong 

    with open ("data/riddles.json", "r") as jason_data:
        data = json.load(jason_data)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_answer.append(request.form["answer"])
        if user_answer [-1] == data[answer_number]["answer"]:
            answer_number += 1
            user_correct += 1
        else:
            user_wrong += 1
        print (answer_number, user_correct, user_wrong)
    return render_template("game_page.html", 
                           user_list = user_list, 
                           riddles_data = data,
                           user_answer=user_answer,
                           answer_number=answer_number)
```

game_page.html code:

```
<form class="form" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
                <label for="name">Write down your answer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" id="answer" name="answer">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing method="POST" in

game_page.html:

```
<form class="form" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Write down your answer</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" id="answer" name="answer">
        </form>
```